# How hard is it to suspend and track a twitter account seeking ransom from govt. organizations?

Tags: email, ip, tracking

Am asking in reference to this Twitter account - [DarkOverlord](https://twitter.com/tdo_h4ck3rs?lang=en) .
It threatened to post decryption keys, for the documents pasted on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4F5R8QyQ) ([archived](https://archive.fo/https://pastebin.com/4F5R8QyQ)), and few minutes ago it did post them.

Couldn't this account be closed and tracked as well ?
Also, it gives an email-ID for correspondence, are VPN's so secure that this mail account origins couldn't be traced?

Comment: It seems likely that this hacker is vastly overexaggerating his claims. To be honest, he sounds more like a well-connected script kiddie with a lot of documents than an actual hacker. It's just the way he talks.

Comment: Twitter closed the account

Comment: @BlueWizard - Yes, they can't tweet now. But, they are again online answering queries here, https://steemit.com/thedarkoverlord/@thedarkoverlord/impersonations-of-thedarkoverlord, on steemit.

Comment: @forest - See, someone paid and purchased a file. Not sure about the authenticity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be closed? Absolutely. Twitter can close any account they would like and the account owner can do nothing about it short of moving their content elsewhere. However, tracking the account creator is a different matter. If they used an anonymity network like Tor, and sandboxed the browser or otherwise protected themselves from the potential of browser exploits, then they would be almost impossible to track. Actually tracking them would either require using very valuable 0days (which may not even be enough, depending on the level of precautions taken), or by hoping the hacker slips up his OPSEC.

Comment: I guess it's riseup mailing system, which they probably used for requesting obsfuscating bridges, that's keeping them safe/untraceable. Anyway, am a very big fan of yours, happy that you replied to my query !

Answer (score 0):

It surely can be closed by Twitter once they get to know that an account has violated the terms & conditions of holding an account with them but there are hundreds to thousands of such accounts ranging from hactivism to cybercrime and they use Twitter as a platform to spread their message. You may try doing report abuse!

With regards to tracing, in the current times it's really hard to trace real source with different anonymous services and VPS services being offered globally at throw away prices. This is the reason, attribution in the current days has become more complex and one may do this only by following an actor and their Indicators for significantly longer times.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter closed the account in the meantime.
This answers you question weather Twitter can do it (they can and they did).